# How to efficiently create a group of animating sprites

Tags: ios, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

How do I batch together multiple CCSprite Objects together if each has multiple frames?
I've looked at CCSpriteBatchNode which works for sprites that are static.
Is there a good way batch together multiple animating sprites?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Texture Packer](http://www.texturepacker.com/download/) for the sprites which uses the animations. Then you can use the CCSpriteBatchNode and maintain Your Animations.